# How to get ArrayList using GET method of volley

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, android-volley

This is the example of ArrayList that i need to fetch, how to fetch this Arrays? Im using GET method of volley to fetch this Array and show in Recycler View.

`[
    {
        "_id": "a2a1",
        "name": "Flower",
        "image": {
            "_id": "a2a2",
            "name": "flower.jpg",
            "url": "/uploads/c8c8c.jpg",
            "related": [
                "a2a1"
            ],
            "id": "0a2a2"
        },
    },
    {
        "_id": "433d",
        "name": "Bouquet",
        "id": "433d",
        "image": {
            "_id": "433e",
            "name": "baloon.jpg",
            "url": "/uploads/247db.jpg",
            "related": [
                "433d"
            ],
            "id": "433e"
        },
    }]`

This is my code by using Get method of Volley to fetch the array, i already put the correct api but i didnt get the list of the array.

```
  private void FlowerList(){

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            ServerApi.URL_FLOWER,

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();


                    if(response != null) {

                        JSONObject json = null;

                        try {
                            json = new JSONObject(response);
                            FlowerModel[] models = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(json.getJSONArray(null)), FlowerModel[].class);
                            flowerAdapter.addBatch(Arrays.asList(models));


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }

    );

    Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(request);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Gson verson 2.8' then

```
try {
                            json = new JSONObject(response);
                           ArrayList<FlowerModel> models = gson.fromJson(response, TypeToken.getParameterized(ArrayList.class, FlowerModel.class).getType());
                            //flowerAdapter.addBatch(Arrays.asList(models));


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

for older version

```
 try {
                                json = new JSONObject(response);
                               ArrayList<FlowerModel> models = gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<ArrayList<FlowerModel>>(){}.getType(););
                                //flowerAdapter.addBatch(Arrays.asList(models));


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....i have modified your code

```
ArrayList<String> stringArrayList;
String id1,name,id2;

StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET,
        ServerApi.URL_FLOWER,

        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();


                if(response != null) {

                    JSONObject json = null;

                    try {
                        json = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray=json.getJSONArray("Your_response_arrayName");
                        stringArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
                        for(i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            stringArrayList.add(jsonObject);


                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }

);

Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(request);

}
```

hope this will help you